# printf/snprintf behavior in 64 bit environment

Tags: c, printf, 64-bit

Printing `0` in 64-bit environment with `%lu` is giving `140733193388032` output.

I am printing 8 times `0` in 64-bit environment and after till 6th the value printing as `0` and last 2 it is printing `140733193388032`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct size {
    unsigned long length;
    unsigned long breadth;
};

struct pad {
    unsigned long len;
    unsigned long bre;
    unsigned char hei;
    unsigned char pad[7];
};

int main() {
    unsigned long a;
    unsigned long b = 0;
    struct size sz;
    struct pad sz1;

    printf("%lu is a, %lu is b , %lu is length, %lu is breadth, %lu is len, "
           "%lu is bre, %lu is hei, %lu is zero\n",
           a, b, sz.length, sz.breadth, sz1.len, sz1.bre, sz1.hei, 0);
    printf("%lu is a, %lu is b , %lu is length, %lu is breadth, %lu is len, "
           "%lu is bre, %lu is hei, %lu is zero",
           0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Output:

```
140737488347824 is a, 0 is b , 0 is length, 4195408 is breadth, 140737346312864 is len, 4195893 is bre, 140733193388064 is hei, 140733193388032 is zero
0 is a, 0 is b , 0 is length, 0 is breadth, 0 is len, 0 is bre, 140733193388032 is hei, 140733193388032 is zero
```

With Initializing struct and local:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct size {
    unsigned long length;
    unsigned long breadth;
};

struct pad {
    unsigned long len;
    unsigned long bre;
    unsigned char hei;
    unsigned char pad[7];
};

int main() {
    unsigned long a = 0;
    unsigned long b = 0;
    struct size sz = { 0 };
    struct pad sz1 = { 0 };

    printf("%lu is a, %lu is b , %lu is length, %lu is breadth, %lu is len, "
           "%lu is bre, %lu is hei, %lu is zero\n",
           a, b, sz.length, sz.breadth, sz1.len, sz1.bre, sz1.hei, 0);
    printf("%lu is a, %lu is b , %lu is length, %lu is breadth, %lu is len, "
           "%lu is bre, %lu is hei, %lu is zero",
           0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Output:

```
0 is a, 0 is b , 0 is length, 0 is breadth, 0 is len, 0 is bre, 140733193388032 is hei, 140733193388032 is zero
0 is a, 0 is b , 0 is length, 0 is breadth, 0 is len, 0 is bre, 140733193388032 is hei, 140733193388032 is zero
```

Comment: Please show the exact code you’re using

Comment: Hi @SamiKuhmonen , Added code snippet

Comment: You’ve never assigned a value to `a` or anything else than `b` so accessing them is undefined behavior. In the second one you’re using the wrong specifier. 0 constant is not 64bit.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen , please see my second snippet. in this hei is also printing bigger value where as others are 0 . 0 i understand now shouldnt use %lu , we should use %u

Comment: @BharathMeduri: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score

Answer (score 1):

The variables you are referring to are uninitialized and contain some garbage from memory. Compiler is not obliged to zero-initialize hence are the numbers. Initialize all variables to zero at declaration, like this:

`memset(&sz, 0, sizeof(sz))`

or all members separately.

**Edit after providing snippet**

I tried to zero-initialize all variables like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct size
{
  unsigned long length;
  unsigned long breadth;
};

struct pad
{
  unsigned long len;
  unsigned long bre;
  unsigned char hei;
  unsigned char pad[7];
};


int main()
{

  unsigned long a = 0;
  unsigned long b = 0;
  struct size sz = { 0 };
  struct pad sz1 = { 0 };

  printf("%lu is a, %lu is b , %lu is length, %lu is breadth, %lu is len, %lu is bre, %lu is hei, %lu is zero\n",a,b,sz.length, sz.breadth, sz1.len, sz1.bre, sz1.hei, 0);
  printf("%lu is a, %lu is b , %lu is length, %lu is breadth, %lu is len, %lu is bre, %lu is hei, %lu is zero",0,0,0,0,0,0, 0, 0);
 }
```

and I got following output:

```
0 is a, 0 is b , 0 is length, 0 is breadth, 0 is len, 0 is bre, 0 is hei, 0 is zero
0 is a, 0 is b , 0 is length, 0 is breadth, 0 is len, 0 is bre, 0 is hei, 0 is zero
```

Comment: Ya this is ok , even if i initialize still the second printf has big value for 0

Comment: This correction is incomplete. You do not have a problem because you compile the code in 32-bit or 64-bit Windows where `unsigned long` is 32-bit, the same size as `unsigned int`.

Comment: I am definitely using 64-bit Windows and 64-bit compiler: `Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/Tools/Strawberry/c/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32`

Comment: OK, but unlike linux and MacOS, 64-bit Windows defines type `unsigned long` with just 32 bits for portability issues, so the problem does not occur on your platform. The arguments must be converted to `unsigned long` for defined behavior on all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct size
{

  unsigned long length;
  unsigned long breadth;
};

struct pad
{
  unsigned long len;
  unsigned long bre;
  unsigned char hei;
  unsigned char pad[7];
};


int main()
{

   unsigned long a = 0;
   unsigned long b = 0;
   struct size sz = {0};
   struct pad sz1= {0};

   printf("%lu is a, %lu is b , %lu is length, %lu is breadth, %lu is len, %lu is 
   bre, %uc is hei, %u is zero\n",a,b,sz.length, sz.breadth, sz1.len, sz1.bre, 
   sz1.hei, 0);
   printf("%u is a, %u is b , %u is length, %u is breadth, %u is len, %u is bre, %u 
   is hei, %u is zero",0,0,0,0,0,0, 0, 0);
  }
```

This output is all 0's

Used -wformat in gcc , fixed warnings then it is printing all 0's

Comment: The code still has undefined behavior if type `unsigned long` and `unsigned int` have a different size. You probably use Windows or a 32-bit system on which the problem does not occur.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems in your code:

- you are printing uninitialized data, the behavior is undefined, the output is unpredictable.
- `sz1.hei` has type `unsigned char`, you should not use format `%lu` or you should cast this value as `(unsigned long)sz1.hei`.
- `0` has type `int`, you should pass `0L` or `0UL` for format `%lu` in your second `printf`.

With the initializers, this code behaves as expected in 32-bit (and 64-bit Windows) because `unsigned long` is 32-bit on thee platforms, the same size as `unsigned int`.

You must pass `printf` arguments with the expected type for each conversion specifier, otherwise the behavior is undefined. You should increase the warning level (for example `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror`) to let the compiler warn you about such mistakes and many others.

Here is a corrected version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

struct size {
    unsigned long length;
    unsigned long breadth;
};

struct pad {
    unsigned long len;
    unsigned long bre;
    unsigned char hei;
    unsigned char pad[7];
};

int main() {
    unsigned long a = 0;
    unsigned long b = 0;
    struct size sz = { 0 };
    struct pad sz1 = { 0 };

    printf("%lu is a, %lu is b , %lu is length, %lu is breadth, %lu is len, "
           "%lu is bre, %lu is hei, %lu is zero\n",
           a, b, sz.length, sz.breadth, sz1.len, sz1.bre, (unsigned long)sz1.hei, 0UL);
    printf("%lu is a, %lu is b , %lu is length, %lu is breadth, %lu is len, "
           "%lu is bre, %lu is hei, %lu is zero",
           0UL, 0UL, 0UL, 0UL, 0UL, 0UL, 0UL, 0UL);
    return 0;
}
```